# Shuffling values in HashMap

Tags: java, collections, shuffle

I would like to shuffle values in an HashMap. I have following type of HashMap

```
Map<Integer,ArrayList<String> > trainDataSet = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
```

I would like to shuffle the values in the Map. How would i do it?

Following is my attempt:

```
    collections.shuffle(trainDataSet.values());
```

Got an error:

```
    Values cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Yes this make sense, because my values are in Arraylist not in List. Would it be possible to shuffle collections of arraylist?

EDIT

If i have following order::

```
key1  [aa,bb,cd]
key2  [xx,xy,sfr]
```

Into something like

```
key1  [xx,xy,sfr]
key2  [aa,bb,cd]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, do you want to shuffle each list on each bucket in the map, or to you want to get all values in the map, and put them in random buckets?

Comment: I would like to get all the values in the map and put them in random buckets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You actually want to randomly reassociate keys and values. Here's an example how that can be achieved:

```
final Map<String, Object> x = new HashMap<String, Object>();
x.put("x", 1); x.put("y", 2); x.put("z", 3); x.put("w", 4);
System.out.println(x);
final List<Object> vs = new ArrayList<Object>(x.values());
Collections.shuffle(vs);
System.out.println(vs);
final Iterator<Object> vIter = vs.iterator();
for (String k : x.keySet()) x.put(k, vIter.next());
System.out.println(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

according to your response on my comment in the original question, here is how you can get all the values in the map and put them in random buckets

```
Random random = new Random();
    Map<Integer,ArrayList<String> > shuffled = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(trainDataSet.keySet());
    for (Integer key : keys) {
        shuffled.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    for (ArrayList<String> values : trainDataSet.values()) {
        for (String string : values) {
            Integer randomKey = random.nextInt(keys.size());
            ArrayList<String> list = shuffled.get(randomKey);
            list.add(string);
            shuffled.put(randomKey, list);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(trainDataSet));
```